# Generate Report in Android application

Tags: android

I have a table which contain products name and their price. i have to generate a report which will show the product name and their price and the summation of total price.i can fetch the data from server but i can't generate the report.

Comment: In Which format do u want to generate the report?

Comment: What is the problem? What format is the report? Where is your code? What is the issue?

Comment: In grid view format. @android_dev